# Na POO quando se deve usar return?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma duvida relacionada a POO, quando devo usar o `return` em um método?!

Visto que quando eu passo um objeto para o método e as modificações são feitas nele, eu não preciso de return, exemplo abaixo:

Chamada do método:

```
this.ordenaArquivo(this.arquivos);

private void ordenaArquivo(List<Video> arquivos ) {     
    VideoComparatorUtil comparatorUtil = new VideoComparatorUtil(VideoComparatorUtil.ORDERBY_TAMANHO);

    Collections.sort(arquivos, comparatorUtil);
}
```

Ou deveria fazer isso:

Chamada do método:

```
this.arquivos = this.ordenaArquivo(this.arquivo);

private List<Video> ordenaArquivo(List<Video> arquivos ) {      
    VideoComparatorUtil comparatorUtil = new VideoComparatorUtil(VideoComparatorUtil.ORDERBY_TAMANHO);

    Collections.sort(arquivos, comparatorUtil);

    return arquivos;
}
```

Comment: Você pode realizar um teste, passe como parâmetro do seu método uma `String` e dentro do seu método, tente alterar esta `String`. algo como isso: `public void changeStringValue(String value) {  value = "Ohh!!"; }`.
e veja que se tentar imprimir o valor da sua `String` após invocar este método, o valor imprimido será o mesmo de antes de invocar o método.

`String myStr = "initialValue" ; `
` System.out.printLn(myStr); //initialValue`
` changeStringValue(myStr);
` System.out.printLn(myStr); //initialValue`

por este motivo, passe os parâmetros, e retorne o resultado, caso necessário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o `return` não chega a ser um conceito específico de orientação a objetos. Faz parte da sintaxe do Java e de muitas outras linguagens e é uma palavra chave usada pra retornar para o código onde o método inicialmente foi chamado.

Um método de tipo qualquer retorna quando encontra o `return` seguido do seu respectivo tipo; 
Um método do tipo `void` retorna quando encontra o `return;` ou quando chega ao fim dele.

Mas a sua dúvida pode ser melhor explicada pelos [tipos de dados do Java e passagem de argumentos por valor ou referência](http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/09/arrays-em-metodos-passagem-por-valor-e_16.html).

### Passagem de argumento por valor

Quando você passa pra um método apenas argumentos de tipos primitivos (int, float, double, long, short, char ou byte), eles são passados `por valor`. Ou seja, uma `cópia` daquela variável é feita dentro do escopo do método e mesmo que você a altere, nada vai acontecer com a variável original que você tinha passado como argumento primeiramente.

```
public static int metodoSomaDois(int argumento) {
    //Uma cópia do seu argumento recebe ele mesmo + 2
    //Sendo assim vc precisa retornar ele caso 
    //queira atribuir o seu valor alterado à uma outra variável externa
    argumento += 2; 
    return argumento;
}
```

Exemplo:

```
 int original = 5;
 metodoSomaDois(original); //Nada vai acontecer já que vc não atribuiu o retorno do método a nenhuma outra variável e a original permanece 5.
 original = metodoSomaDois(original); //Agora a variável original vai receber o valor retornado do método
```

### Passagem de argumento por referência (o seu caso)

Já argumentos de tipos não primitivos (arrays, objetos e etc) são passados por `referência`. Isso significa que o objeto em si é passado (mais precisamente um ponteiro pra aquele objeto) e não uma cópia. Ou seja, qualquer mudança feita naquele objeto dentro do escopo do método **também vai alterar** o objeto que foi originalmente passado como argumento.

```
public static void metodoAlteraValores(int listaPorArgumento[]) {
    //Como esta sendo passado por referência
    //os valores da lista original vão ser alterados também sem a necessidade de atribuir o retorno
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        listaPorArgumento[i] = 10;
}
```

Exemplo:

```
int lista[] = {5, 5, 5};

    for (int i : lista)
        System.out.print(i + ", "); //Exibe 5, 5, 5,

    metodoAlteraValores(lista); //Altera os valores pra 10 sem precisar de atribuir a nenhuma outra variável

    for (int i : lista)
        System.out.print(i + ", "); //Exibe 10, 10, 10, (o que mostra que a lista original foi alterada)
```

### Conclusão

Isso mostra que o seu primeiro exemplo é o mais correto e o porque. 
De forma resumida, o `return` vai ser utilizado quando você precisar retornar um valor que tenha que ser atribuído a alguma variável, e não será necessário quando for alterar diretamente um objeto que for passado por referência.

Vale lembrar que é possível retornar um objeto de tipo não primitivo, que pode ser atribuído a uma variável do mesmo tipo. Normalmente isso acontece quando você, por exemplo, quer alterar um array sem alterar o original. 
Sendo assim, o ideal, para o seu caso, seria criar um objeto do mesmo tipo dentro do método e fazer um clone do original que possa ser alterado e posteriormente retornado.

Comment: Perfeito, não havia parado para pensar que tipo primitivos de variáveis não eram alterados quando passado para um método, ótima resposta, muito obrigado.

Comment: Não concordo com o enquadramento do problema. O problema não se trata apenas de passagem de argumentos por referência vs por valor, mas sim de tipos imutáveis (primitivos ou não) vs tipos mutáveis (não primitivos). Por exemplo, `string` é passado por referência - no entanto, quaisquer "alterações" devem ser retornadas, visto `string` ser um tipo imutável.

Comment: Acredito que a resposta não carece informações. A dúvida era de quando se deve usar o return. Eu respondi e até extrapolei um pouco explicando e exemplificando passagem por referência usando array, que é bem próximo do exemplo que ele usou na pergunta. Poderia explicar diretamente sobre imutabilidade também, mas diante do que já foi escrito, cabe a ele ir atrás de mais informações já que tudo isto esta conectado.

Answer (score 1):

Em java todo objeto é passado como referência. Logo, se voce quer alterar um objeto em um método, é suficiente passar ele como parâmetro e sem retorno. No seu caso, a primeira opção parece melhor (Lists são objetos).

Se mesmo assim você quiser retornar um objeto, note que ao usar return em um objeto voce não retorna uma cópia dele, retorna apenas a referência para este objeto. Então, return na lista não retorna uma cópia completa da lista, retorna apenas uma referência para sua lista.

Usa-se retorno apenas para tipos primitivos (int, float ...) que em Java são passados por valor;